# Type of lambda expression

Tags: lambda, scheme

I want to ask,if one asks what is the type of lambda expression for this lambda expression,what will be the answer? Is it something like the type of result after completing that lambda expression?

For example : what is the type of lambda expression for this expression

```
(lambda (s) (string-append s s))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a function with one parameter, so it has the type `a -> b` for some `a` and `b`.

Since it passes `s` to `string-append`, `s` must be a string.
The result of `string-append` is also a string, so the type is `string -> string`.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme is dynamically typed, this object will satisfy the PROCEDURE? predicate but other than that it does not have a type.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Generally this would be better as a comment, but I realize you may not have enough rep to do so yet. It would be great if you could edit your answer to include some additional information, and make it more complete.